# How to draw only a portion of sprite sheet to CCGLSurfaceView in Android Cocos2D?

Tags: android, sprite-sheet, cocos2d-android

I am starting out Android Cocos2D from [here](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/). I see that a sprite image can be added directly.

However, I already got myself a huge sprite sheet, it got every single sprites used in the game.

Is there some sort of function call in Cocos2D that I can simply just specify "I want to draw a portion (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) from the sprite sheet to a location on CCGLSurfaceView"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCSpriteSheet is deprecated. It's better to use CCSpriteBatchNode instead (actually they are very similar). You can create sprites from batchNode:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batch rect:CGRectMake(x1, y1, x2, y2)];
```

That's the objective-c code, but i thinks there is the same function in android version

Comment: It seems Android Cocos2D is using older port of iPhone Cocos2D in the template file. It seems I will need to compile from source if I need this.